# Get template to work well with unique_ptr to interfaces in C++

Tags: c++11, inheritance, interface, unique-ptr, dynamic-cast

First of all, there's no such built in concept as "interface". By interface in C++, I really mean some abstract base class that looks like:

```
struct ITreeNode
{
   ... // some pure virtual functions
};
```

Then we can have concrete structs that implement the interface, such as:

```
struct BinaryTreeNode : public ITreeNode
{
   BinaryTreeNode* LeftChild;
   BinaryTreeNode* RightChild;

// plus the overriden functions
};
```

It makes good sense: `ITreeNode` is an interface; not every implementation has `Left` & `Right` children - only `BinaryTreeNode` does.

To make things widely reusable, I want to write a template. So the `ITreeNode` needs to be `ITreeNode<T>`, and `BinaryTreeNode` needs to be `BinaryTreeNode<T>`, like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct BinaryTreeNode : public ITreeNode<T>
{
};
```

To make things even better, let's use unique pointer(smart point is more common, but I know the solution - dynamic_pointer_cast).

```
template<typename T>
struct BinaryTreeNode : public ITreeNode<T>
{
   typedef std::shared_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<T>> SharedPtr;
   typedef std::unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<T>> UniquePtr;
   // ... other stuff
};
```

Likewise,

```
template<typename T>
struct ITreeNode
{
   typedef std::shared_ptr<ITreeNode<T>> SharedPtr;
   typedef std::unique_ptr<ITreeNode<T>> UniquePtr;
};
```

It's all good, until this point:
Let's assume now we need to write a class BinaryTree.

There's a function insert that takes a value T and insert it into the root node using some algorithm(naturally it will be recursive).

In order to make the function testable, mockable and follow good practice, the arguments need to be interface, rather than concrete classes. (Let's say this is a rigid rule that cannot be broken.)

```
template<typename T>
void BinaryTree<T>::Insert(const T& value, typename ITreeNode<T>::UniquePtr& ptr)
{
   Insert(value, ptr->Left); // Boooooom, exploded
   // ...
}
```

Here's the problem:
Left is not a field of ITreeNode! And worst of all, you cannot cast a `unique_ptr<Base>` to `unique_ptr<Derived>`!

What's the best practice for a scenario like this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your insertion algorithm seems flawed. For example, TreeNodes could handle insertion within themselves. In other words, your `BinaryTree::Insert` method could simply call `root->insert(value)`. Then let the TreeNode implementation worry about inserting the value in the correct spot or recursing down to its children.

Comment: I think your problem here is assuming that `BinaryTreeNode` should be able to operate on any arbitrary `ITreeNode`. It probably shouldn't. If you want to stick to an 'interface only' paradigm, you could increate an `IBinaryTreeNode` interface that defines that data model. However, typically you don't insert *nodes* into a binary tree, you insert *values*. The only time you'd ever insert a node would be when that node is actually another tree, in which case requiring the concrete class makes sense.

Comment: Ummm... how would you like to insert a tree node into a binary tree. You can do it only with `BinaryTreeNode`. To me your `Insert` says "You can use me to insert any tree node into the `BinaryTree`", which it's not true. You need a `IBinaryTreeNode` which derives from `ITreeNode`.

Comment: Alternatively, as @AtlasC1 suggests, if you really should be able to insert arbitrary nodes into arbitrary trees (which just seems like a bad idea, but your call), then `Insert` should be a method of `ITreeNode` and it should return an `ITreeNode`. You can then use a variation of the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and perhaps some double-dispatch/visitor pattern to get it right. But again, being able to combine arbitrary trees doesn't really seem sensical. The key is remembering that what is generic about trees is inserting *values*, not *nodes*

Comment: @aruisdante yeah, the user of `BinaryTree` really should not need to be aware of the underlying node structure, because that would allow them to insert the wrong types of nodes, as you mentioned. The API should really look more like this: `BinaryTree<T>::Insert(const T& value)`, or at the very least only accept a `BinaryTreeNode` as the second argument (though, as I mentioned earlier, this is something the user shouldn't even know about).

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. The algorithm itself is not the key thing here(In fact, the first argument is the value to be inserted; the second argument is the node that serves as a temporary 'root' of the subtree). The question WAS about unique_ptr conversion in order to point to the derived type for the Left/Right memeber access. Now with the advice from @aruisdante and luk32 the problem IS my bad design which did NOT introduce IBinaryTreeNode. Also thanks for the template method pattern - good stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, over-engineering it is!  But note that, for the most part, such low level data structures benefit HUGELY from transparency and simple memory layouts.  Placing the level of abstraction above the container can give significant performance boosts.

```
template<class T>
struct ITreeNode {
  virtual void insert( T const & ) = 0;
  virtual void insert( T      && ) = 0;

  virtual T const* get() const = 0;
  virtual T      * get()       = 0;
  // etc
  virtual ~ITreeNode() {}
};

template<class T>
struct IBinaryTreeNode : ITreeNode<T> {
  virtual IBinaryTreeNode<T> const* left()  const = 0;
  virtual IBinaryTreeNode<T> const* right() const = 0;

  virtual std::unique_ptr<IBinaryTreeNode<T>>& left()  = 0;
  virtual std::unique_ptr<IBinaryTreeNode<T>>& right() = 0;

  virtual void replace(T const &) = 0;
  virtual void replace(T      &&) = 0;
};

template<class T>
struct BinaryTreeNode : IBinaryTreeNode<T> {
  // can be replaced to mock child creation:
  std::function<std::unique_ptr<IBinaryTreeNode<T>>()> factory
    = {[]{return std::make_unique<BinaryTreeNode<T>>();} };

  // left and right kids:
  std::unique_ptr<IBinaryTreeNode<T>> pleft;
  std::unique_ptr<IBinaryTreeNode<T>> pright;

  // data.  I'm allowing it to be empty:
  std::unique_ptr<T> data;

  template<class U>
  void insert_helper( U&& t ) {
    if (!get()) {
      replace(std::forward<U>(t));
    } else if (t < *get()) {
      if (!left()) left() = factory();
      assert(left());
      left()->insert(std::forward<U>(t));
    } else {
      if (!right()) right() = factory();
      assert(right());
      right()->insert(std::forward<U>(t));
    }
  }
  // not final methods, allowing for balancing:
  virtual void insert( T const&t ) override { // NOT final
    return insert_helper(t);
  }
  virtual void insert( T &&t ) override { // NOT final
    return insert_helper(std::move(t));
  }
  // can be empty, so returns pointers not references:
  T const* get() const override final {
    return data.get();
  }
  T      * get()       override final {
    return data.get();
  }
  // short, could probably skip:
  template<class U>
  void replace_helper( U&& t ) {
    data = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<U>(t));
  }
  // only left as customization points if you want.
  // could do this directly:
  virtual void replace(T const & t) override final {
    replace_helper(t);
  }
  virtual void replace(T      && t) override final  {
    replace_helper(std::move(t));
  }
  // Returns pointers, because no business how we store it in a const
  // object:
  virtual IBinaryTreeNode<T> const* left()  const final override {
    return pleft.get();
  }
  virtual IBinaryTreeNode<T> const* right() const final override {
    return pright.get();
  }
  // returns references to storage, because can be replaced:
  // (could implement as getter/setter, but IBinaryTreeNode<T> is
  // "almost" an implementation class, some leaking is ok)
  virtual std::unique_ptr<IBinaryTreeNode<T>>& left() final override {
    return pleft;
  }
  virtual std::unique_ptr<IBinaryTreeNode<T>>& right() final override {
    return pright;
  }
};
```

Comment: Returning `data.get()` should have the same effect as `data?data.get():nullptr`.

Comment: @templateboy True.  If that is the only problem with that wall of code, I'd be surprised.  :)

Comment: `ITreeNode::get` should have `virtual` as well. :)

Comment: I'm trying to understand the design decisions you made here. Why does `ITreeNode` have a pure virtual `insert` function? Isn't it the job of the actual tree to handle insertion, not the nodes themselves?

Comment: @templateboy Well, a `ITreeNode` is both a node of a tree, and an entire tree itself?  The root of a tree is sort of a tree.

Comment: Thanks Yakk. Introducing IBinaryTreeNode is indeed the right thing to do. I get the idea, leave the details of implementation to me. Cheers.

Comment: Another question: why do you think it's over-engineering? Shouldn't real world production code be written this way? For example, without introducing all those "interfaces", how do you use mock? My impression is, all mock libraries work ONLY with interfaces(in C++ case, that's actually Abstract Base Class), specifically NOT with concrete classes because it will need run time behaviour substitution. Without mock it's very difficult to write good unit tests, which soon leads the code base to a mess.

Comment: Also, smart pointers are also encouraged to be used in real production code isn't it? Raw pointers, along with the ambiguity of ownership that came with them, cause memory leaks that are hard to detect. Can you be more specific regarding the proper engineering practices we should follow in a production environment?

Comment: A tree is a low level data structure with high reusability, and should be written with performance in mind.  If you want to do mock-based testing on it, do compile-time mocking: interfaces are interfaces, be they duck based or virtual function tables.

Comment: If by compile-time mocking you were referring to the approach with templates for compile time polymorphism, I don't see how it can help. Assume now the function insert takes a BinaryTreeNode rather than an IBinaryTreeNode interface, and you need to test this function. You'll have to create a BinaryTreeNode to pass into the insert function. This approach does not work with complex dependencies. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @h9uest it takes a `template<class IBinaryTreeNode>` where that type obeys a duck type inerface you specify formally.  If you need to expose a fixed type, the actual exposed one takes an actual fixed type signature (or even fixed template signature), and forwards to the compile-time-mockable one.  Now we can eliminate runtime abstraction overhead.

Comment: I consider `std::map` overly slow (single node tree): yours looks as bad, plus vtable overhead, plus abstraction wall overhead (cannot optimize cross abstraction barriers).  Low level datastructures should be as safe as houses and fast as hand-crafted C/assembly, because if good, they are used *everywhere*, so any slowness pollutes entire codebase.  Saying you need them to be (say) 2x slower due to a particular testing pattern means find a new testing pattern.  Non-reused code you can slack on, as if it is fast enough it is fast enough.